# Using where method with List<Map> Dart

Tags: list, api, dictionary, dart, flutter

I have a problem in flutter I want to do a search bar and I have a response to an api and I want to show data from server that contains a text from search bar my problem is where method doesn't work with List any ideas ?

Comment: what error do you get? could you show us the code you use?

Comment: `var map = [{
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    'address':"Flangomn",
    "lat":"27.012",
    'lng':"43.12"
  }];
    
    if (this._searchQuery.text == query && this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isSearching = false;
        if (map != null) {
          for(var i = 0; i <map.length; i++)
          _results = jsonDecode(map[i]['address']).where((p)=>p.startsWith(query)).toList();
        } else {
          _error = 'Error searching';
        }
      });
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comment, there is no `where` method on `String` types. Instead of the `for` loop, you want something along these lines:

```
// Remove the for loop
// for(var i = 0; i <map.length; i++) { _results = jsonDecode(map[i]['address']).where((p)=>p.startsWith(query)).toList(); }

// Do this instead
_results = map.where((item) => item['address'].startsWith(query)).toList();
```

You should now be able to ditch the for loop.

Comment: You Answer is true i found it yesterday after this post by 2 hours